# Download m3u8 using Using react-native-fs in react native

Tags: react-native, download, m3u8

I have m3u8 url link and i want to download stream using download url but not able to download it the complete folder

```
  const destination_url = RNFS.LibraryDirectoryPath + "filelink"
    const dnd_url = url
    RNFS.downloadFile({
      fromUrl: dnd_url,
      toFile: destination_url
    }).promise.then(res => {
      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        
      }
    })
```

But not getting that how i will get full folder in my storage. Let me know if anybody have a good idea about it.

Comment: I tried that but was unable to do that. So I download mp4 of video for caching and play m3u8 for first time and then play mp4. As I guess local m3u8 doesn't support by react-native-video.

Comment: You find any solution?